Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::NotFound: [404][{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index
I am getting this error from Kibana Elasticsearch when I call a POST query command:
#<Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::NotFound: [404] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index [ietb1_2404240017_testtest_cgr_pidstat]","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"ietb1_2404240017_testtest_cgr_pidstat","index_uuid":"na","index":"ietb1_2404240017_testtest_cgr_pidstat"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index [ietb1_2404240017_testtest_cgr_pidstat]","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"ietb1_2404240017_testtest_cgr_pidstat",
Looks like it is saying my index is not found but I can see such index in the Elastic Discover UI area:

Have been stuck for days without a clue.  Thank you
Checking index as Val suggested and I can see:


Are you sure that your index still exists, i.e. it hasn't been deleted by an ILM policy? What do you get when running GET _cat/indices/ietb1*?v ?

As Val said, I would check firstly if the index is there: GET /_cat/indices/ietb1_2404240017_testtest_cgr_pidstat
I assume you already checked it. Can this be a user permission issue? Can you please check your user in Stack Management - Kibana Users and check the user roles? Since it is a POST query, you may need extra permissions. You can check it with this as well: GET /_security/user/

I followed what Val said and I can see the index and I post the result above

Murat, I don't see any User under Stack Management.  I can only see Index Patterns, Saved Objects and Advanced Settings.   No Users inside Advanced Settings as well :(

Murat again, /_security/user/ does not work at all.  I don't think we have any user setup
